# Keep track of different svn subdirectories working together

Tags: svn, configuration, revision, subdirectory

I have a project on SVN with different directories. One of the directories includes the software releases, and the others are infrastructure to use the software releases (e.g. read internal hardware registers, etc.). How can I keep track of which revision of the infrastructures is working with which of the software release versions?

Answer (score 0):

Move *physical* infrastructure into some other location(s), re-create *logical* tree at the old location(s), using PEG-ed externals definitions

But,it current state: each SVN revision store and link all objects in all trees in the whole repository (revision is **global**) - if you'll commit `/release` with properly formed previosly `/infrastructure/...` you can later do nothing: update to any older revision and `/infrastructure/...` will be updated to the state of this revision at commit time also

BTW, I feel. you manufacture to yourself the complexity of the blue

Comment: Unfortunately the SVN has not been used properly and I only have inherited this. I can not restructure the SVN as there are many others using it, so I can not make an /infrastructure module.

Comment: @Brunisboy - anyway, I can't see any troubles in your case (if you have good QA|Release Manager). You have to describe problems (for me) more deeply for more correct and detailed solution